# Caliburn Micro, set focus from MV

Tags: wpf, mvvm, windows-phone-8, caliburn.micro

How to bind UI element (like textBox) focus to view model?

I have Windows Phone app with pivot control. Based on active pivot item I want to set focus to certain text box. Also when user inserts text to text box and hit enter, I want to set focus somewhere else than the text box to close virtual keyboard.

How to do this with Caliburn Micro, view model?

Comment: This type of interaction should happen in the view, not the view model, perhaps using the behaviors defined by System.Windows.Interactivity

Comment: From view, how do I capture event that user hits enter and set focus somewhere else than text box? Based on my current design, I need to handle this from view model.

Comment: Then you should change your design. The ViewModel has no access to events nor should it have to. It should never be used for UI interaction. That's the View's job. You can even handle events in pure XAML using System.Windows.Interactivity behaviors, triggers and actions.

Comment: Any examples or tutorials? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont think you can do that through C.M. I would write a behavior like this:

```
public class BindableFocusBehavior : Behavior<Control>
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty HasFocusProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("HasFocus", typeof(bool), typeof(BindableFocusBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(default(bool), HasFocusUpdated));

    private static void HasFocusUpdated(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((BindableFocusBehavior)d).SetFocus();
    }

    public bool HasFocus
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(HasFocusProperty); }
        set { SetValue(HasFocusProperty, value); }
    }

    private void SetFocus()
    {
        if (HasFocus)
        {
            AssociatedObject.Focus();
        }
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
<TextBox>
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <wpfApplication2:BindableFocusBehavior HasFocus="{Binding SetFocus}"/>
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</TextBox>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hmmm, I got error: "'System.Windows.UIElement' does not contain a definition for 'Focus'..." Im I missing something?

Comment: You need to change Behavior<UIElement> to Behavior<Control> in order to get this working on WP.

Comment: I am trying to insert your BindableFocusBehavior class in a Universal App project and I have not referenced the "Behavior" derived class even if I insered "using Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity;
using Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core;". What I am missing to make it compile? Thank you